# Restrict ui-bootstrap modal to window height

Tags: modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

How do I stop a long modal from going below the fold? I'd like the modal to be compeltely visible and always show the submit cancel buttons.  Is there an easy way to achieve this using ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the css I use for this

```
.modal-dialog {
    height:calc(100% - 60px);
}
    .modal-dialog .modal-content {
        height: 100%;
    }
        .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
            height: calc(100% - 120px);
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc